# Own rewrite rule for special urls in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I've a database-table with some user generated content. Each content-element is available via /my-url/project/the-projects-name . The items are NO wordpress posts. I've created an index-script where I redirect to when such an URL is called. The script then extracts the projects-name, put it in a variable and includes a page-template.
My page and the project-data are displayed well, but wordpress throws a 404-state for the requested website as well as setting the title to "Not Found!". How can I fake wordpress the output??

My htaccess which redirects to my index-projects.php-script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-url/project/(.*)
RewriteRule . /index-project.php [L]
```

my index-project.php:

```
ob_start();

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

while(empty($path[0]))
    array_shift($path);

while(empty($path[count($path)-1]))
    array_pop ($path);

if(count($path) >= 3 && !empty($path[2])) {

$postFound = false;                             // use this param to define if   requested post was found in DB
$post_name = $path[2];                          // get the post name from url

$args = parse_url($post_name);

$slug = $args['path'];   // extract the post slug from post name

if(!empty($slug)) {
    $wp_did_header = true;

    $_GET['page_id'] = SOME_ID_OF_MY_WP_PAGE;
    $_GET['main_page'] = 'page-project';
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();

    include('./wp-content/themes/my-theme/page-project.php');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/my-url/project/(.*) /index-project.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/index-project.php - [L]
```

and make sure you put it about the WP rules in your htaccess

Comment: Wordpress still throws an 404. The page is correctly loaded and the content is "redirected" to my index-project.php but WP still returns the 404-header to the browser...

Comment: I guess there is something that has to be added to the index-project.php script to tell wordpress doesn't to search for the page/post requested by the url

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress still throws an 404. The page is correctly loaded and the content is "redirected" to my index-project.php but WP still returns the 404-header to the browser:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^my-url/project/(.*) /index-project.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/index-project.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```